# CoreML fails to predict: Input Image size does not match

Tags: ios, coreml, coremltools, createml

I created a Model using CreateML Style Transfer template, the output tab shows, input/output image size 512x512, But I am capturing the video at 1080x1920. When I try to Stylize the image it gives me the following error. How can make it flexible to any size or change it to 1080x1920 in the MLModel file itself?

`[coreml] Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "Input image feature image does not match model description" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Input image feature image does not match model description, NSUnderlyingError=0x282d1e820 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Image size 1080 x 1920 not in allowed set of image sizes" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Image size 1080 x 1920 not in allowed set of image sizes}}}`

Comment: The error message is very clearly telling you what the problem is. Also, has nothing to do with Metal.

Comment: If you want help, I would suggest providing the your coremltools conversion script. Also, you may want to google "coremltools add flexible sizes" and you will find tutorials such as this: https://rockyshikoku.medium.com/set-flexible-input-shape-for-coreml-model-9b873fda5310

Comment: Thanks for responding Jeshua, I passed through that error, But how can I convert the output back to 1080*1920, Now the output is of size 512*512 which is the input size of the model? I have trained my model using CreateML I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you change the input and output dimensions to what you need (1080x1920) unless you really want inference at 512x512. The input and output dimensions can be specified in the coremltools conversion script.